# Why do browsers disallow script closing an opener window, yet allow changing its location?

Tags: web-browser, javascript

Browsers typically [don't allow a child tab/window to close its opener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122173/641534) with script. And yet they do allow the child to [alter the location of the opener tab/window](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79628/10864).

This leads to [a curious workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38900492/641534) whereby you can create a page that does nothing but close itself with script as soon as its loaded, and then change the location of the parent tab/window to this new page, effectively closing it.

Which leads me to ask, what security issue lead to disabling the ability to close an opener tab/window, and does this workaround effectively create a back door?

Comment: I don't  know if you will get any definitive answer as to why this choice was made by the browser developers (opinions). but my guess is in the one case closing tabs/windows is/was an annoyance and was abused and in the other case navigating via changing locations was convenient and perhaps less abused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Browsers typically [don't allow a child tab/window to close its opener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122173/641534) with script. And yet they do allow the child to [alter the location of the opener tab/window](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79628/10864).

This is not entirely accurate. If you read the quoted MDN text more carefully, it is actually referring to the opening of the `parent`, **not** the relationship to its `popup`. The actual restriction you are probably running into is:

- Scripts may only close windows were originally opened by script.

So in your specific example, the `popup` was opened by a script, but the `opener` was opened by a user, and therefore the `opener` cannot be `close`d by either itself or the `popup`.

Imagine a scenario where there are two popups

- User-opened tab (cannot be `close`d)
- Popup 1 (`opener` is user-opened tab)
- Popup 2 (`opener` is popup 1)

Popup 2 **can** `close` popup 1 in this scenario.
However, popup 1 cannot `close` the user-opened tab because that violates the rule above.

- In Chrome & Firefox, it does not matter whether the `popup`s are same origin as their `opener`s. The `popup` can change the `location` or `close` the `opener` as desired, subject to my first point above.
- In IE11, the `popup` can `close` the `parent`, but cannot change `parent.location` unless it it meets [Same Origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). (results in new popup if you try)

Also, I'd like to clarify that any `opener` can `close` its own `popup`s or change their `location` without restriction. Access to the `popup` contents is still subject to Same Origin policy for security reasons.

> This leads to [a curious workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38900492/641534) whereby you can create a page that does nothing but close itself with script as soon as its loaded, and then change the location of the parent tab/window to this new page, effectively closing it. ... does this workaround effectively create a back door?

To answer your question directly, there is no such workaround. The linked example will produce the error:

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Unless you are in a 2-popup situation as I explained above, in which case the `popup` could just `close` its `opener` directly. The workaround would be unnecessary in that case though.

Comment: I don't think you're right here. Firefox, for example, does not allow a child tab/window to call close() on its opener, only the opener can close the child. Even if they are of the same origin. However it will allow the child to change the openers location.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: *"does not allow a child tab/window to call close() on its opener"* Where did you see this? I suspect it was oversimplified. The exact rules used are ● outlined in my answer. My testing indicates that children can close their opener if they meet the rules outlined.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy, Same-Origin Policy allows cross-origin `Read/write` access to `window.location`.

Comment: Are you sure Firefox does not allow changing the opener location cross-origin? It worked in my brief testing. Also, they aren't saying the popup closes the main window, just itself after it redirects the main window.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, Thanks, I've corrected the sentence about Firefox.

Comment: *"Also, they aren't saying the popup closes the main window, just itself after it redirects the main window."* Your sentence is unclear. ● A popup can close 'itself' without touching the main window. ● The main window can close itself if itself is a popup. ● The popup can close the main window without redirect workarounds if the main window is also a popup.

Comment: Sorry. I think you are right after all. It seems that I was getting confused because my parent was itself opened in a tab, so there were actually three levels of parent-child tab. The top level parent couldn't be refreshed this way. I found out it was uneccessary coupling anyway. Better to put the child in a variable and use the onunload and onbeforeunload events.

Comment: No mention at all of the security issue that letting scripts close windows poses :(